# Youtube and vimeo frame in django

Tags: django, youtube, vimeo, textile

I'm using textfield with textile and I want to paste youtube or Vimeo frame. Do you have any idea ?? I don't want to have another field.
I want to paste frame to my textfield and don't add any other template code

Comment: Could you a bit more specific? How exactly is the textile content being saved/rendered?

Comment: If you paste youtube frame and you save it , it's just a text, because textile knows only [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language)) characters. Maybe it's possible to do but I'm not sure.